# Max rectangle area using Lagrange multipliers

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> $P=2x+2y$ and we are looking for $S=xy$ so $S$ need to be max

$L=xy+\lambda(2x+2y-P)$

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}: y+2\lambda=0$

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}: x+2\lambda=0$

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda}: 2x+2y-P=0$

$y+2\lambda=0\Rightarrow y=-2\lambda$

$x+2\lambda=0\Rightarrow x=-2\lambda$

$xy=4\lambda^2$

I know it is a simple question but I want to make sure I understand.

So what is the answer? $4\lambda^2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Lagrange multipliers problem, you will typically get a solution for your variables in terms of $\lambda$, like you did here. The second to last step is to use the constraint again to eliminate $\lambda$: $$P=2x+2y=4\lambda+4\lambda=8\lambda,$$ $$\lambda=\frac{P}{8}.$$ Thus, $x=\frac{P}{4}$ and $y=\frac{P}{4}$. The last step is to now use these values to find the max/min for the original problem, i.e., plug these into the equation for $S$.

You made two mistakes which cancel each other out. First, the correct form of $L$ is $$L=xy-\lambda(2x+2y-P).$$ But when you took the derivatives, you came out with the correct form.

Comment: But $P$ is again a function of x and y

Comment: No, $P$ is your constraint, it is a constant. Whatever values $x$ and $y$ have, they have to satisfy $2x+2y=P$.

Answer (score 1):

i have $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=y+2\lambda$$
a solution without Lagrange Multiplier: $$\sqrt{xy}\le \frac{x+y}{2}=\frac{2x+2y}{4}=\frac{P}{4}$$

Comment: Edited, I saw some write $\mathcal{L}(x,y,\lambda)=f(x,y)-\lambda(g(x,y))$ or $\mathcal{L}(x,y,\lambda)=f(x,y)+\lambda(g(x,y))$